# How to write a correct path to picture?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I have a file (jquerymenucss.js) in app/assets/javascripts. And I have a picture (arrow-down.gif) in app/assets/images. But this picture in not view on page!!! (view a empty picture).

How to correct write a path?

My js file:

```
  var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'arrow-down.gif', 25], right:['rightarrowclass', 'arrow-right.gif']}

var jquerycssmenu={

fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 100}, //duration of fade in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid, arrowsvar){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, subulw:$subul.outerWidth(), subulh:$subul.outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            $subul.css({top:this.istopheader? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0})
            $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader? {paddingRight: arrowsvar.down[2]} : {}).append(
                '<img src="'+ (this.istopheader? arrowsvar.down[1] : arrowsvar.right[1])
                +'" class="' + (this.istopheader? arrowsvar.down[0] : arrowsvar.right[0])
                + '" style="border:0;" />'
            )
            $curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    this._offsets={left:$(this).offset().left, top:$(this).offset().top}
                    var menuleft=this.istopheader? 0 : this._dimensions.w
                    menuleft=(this._offsets.left+menuleft+this._dimensions.subulw>$(window).width())? (this.istopheader? -this._dimensions.subulw+this._dimensions.w : -this._dimensions.w) : menuleft
                    $targetul.css({left:menuleft+"px"}).fadeIn(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.overduration)
                },
                function(e){
                    $(this).children("ul:eq(0)").fadeOut(jquerycssmenu.fadesettings.outduration)
                }
            ) //end hover
        }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'})
    }) //end document.ready
}
}

//build menu with ID="myjquerymenu" on page:
jquerycssmenu.buildmenu("myjquerymenu", arrowimages)
```

**css file**

```
.jquerycssmenu {
    font: bold 12px Verdana;
    padding-left: 30px; /*offset of tabs relative to browser left edge*/
}

.jquerycssmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    /*Top level list items*/
.jquerycssmenu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

    /*Top level menu link items style*/
.jquerycssmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 20px 10px 0;
    margin-right: 3px; /*spacing between tabs*/
    color: #aa9685;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.jquerycssmenu ul li a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}

    /*1st sub level menu*/
.jquerycssmenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #973133;
}

    /*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    float: none;
}

    /*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
}

    /* Sub level menu links style */
.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a {
    font: normal 13px Verdana;
    width: 160px; /*width of sub menus*/
    background: #761f20;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a:hover { /*sub menus hover style*/
    background: #b14546;
    color: black;
}

    /* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

.downarrowclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 5px;

}

.rightarrowclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: write the path relative to the page the image gets displayed on

Comment: You should give more information (e.g. where the respective assets are and how they are referenced by each other).

Answer (score 1):

If you're assigning the image path *in JavaScript*, for instance the `src` property of an `img` element, then the path will be relative to the *document* (not the script you're running it in). The path is relative to the document's URL *as the client sees it*.

(This is different from CSS, where the path is relative to the URL the client sees for the CSS file, not the document the CSS file is used in.)

So for instance:

- If the client (browser) sees the document at `http://www.example.com/foo/document.html`, and your code is included (from anywhere) in that document, and the actual URL the image is served on is (guessing) `http://www.example.com/assets/images/down-arrow.gif`, then you'd need `../assets/images/down-arrow.gif` or `/assets/images/down-arrow.gif`.
- If the client sees the document at `http://example.com/doc.html` and the image is on `http://example.com/app/assets/images/down-arrow.gif`, then the relative path is `app/assets/images/down-arrow.gif` (or `/app/assets/images/down-arrow.gif`).

Comment: and how I write this string in js: var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'app/assets/images/arrow-down.gif', 25] ?

Comment: @Cat: It's a string. You write it like any other string. Since you've never said what the relationship is between the external URL of the document and the external URL of the image, it's impossible to tell you exactly what you need. But the above tells **you** how to figure it out. It's a relative URL, relative to the document the image is in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead set on just having all your plugin in one (JS) file and not use an extra CSS file you should use absolute URLs. Since you'll probably be including your plugin in all forms of pages (foo/, bar/this, there/is/only/zuul). Compare [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619760/3022387). From the CSS file you can use relative URLs, relative to the CSS file.